# JavaFX - Translating a Label (over time)

Tags: java, javafx, label, translate-animation

I want to translate my `Label` over time by responding to a simple `Math.sin` function to create a "floating effect". My first idea was to create an infinite `Task` at startup that updates a `DoubleProperty` 60 times per second, and to bind this property to the `translateYProperty` from the Label. But it doesn't work everytime and the `onMouseClicked` action of the Label isn't executed correctly.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the exact problem with that code?

Comment: @IvanPronin https://pastebin.com/274Unt5f
The titlePosition property is binded to my Label's translateYPosition.
When I click on the label it changes the application theme by changing my root's -fx-base style property. It works for every element except the scene background color. Without the animation it works well.

Comment: OK so you mean something similar to an html Marquee  but with a fixed size?

Comment: [Interpolator.EASE_BOTH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Interpolator.html#EASE_BOTH) is the [default Interpolator of Transitions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html#setInterpolator-javafx.animation.Interpolator-), including [TranslateTransitions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html).  I suspect this will do what you want, even though it’s not actually a sine wave.

Comment: Use the [animation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html). Probably just subclass [`Transition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html) and implement the `interpolate()` method to position the label.

Comment: @VGR + James_D : That was what I was looking for. Thanks !